# Tomcat 7.0.57 and IIS 8.5 compatibility

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, iis-8.5, isapi-redirect

I have been searching a lot but confused , so here for help .

I need to migrate an application which is running on 2008 Windows , Tomcat 4.1.2 , Oracle 11 to Windows 2012 version with IIS 8.5 version .

Can someone help me with the correct tomcat , java version and oracle compatibility as i see tomcat 6 and 8  have reached EOL and wont be supported. Can i use Tomcat 7.0.57 and how can i configure IIS 8.5 with this version using ISAPI redirectors ?

Also i am not a developer , so do i need to look into code as well due to version changes which might impact APIs and methods ?

Need your guidance .

Comment: What makes you assume that Tomcat 7 has reached EOL? (Hint: [It didn't](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html)). Either way, if you're touching the application right now, I'd upgrade it to the latest available one (9), so that you don't have to run past EOL soon. An assumption about announcement of Tomcat 7 EOL will be made once Tomcat 10 is out, as the ASF is striving to keep 3 releases in parallel. But you'll have some warning time, and nothing has been announced yet.

Comment: Also: You specifically mention Tomcat 7.0.57, which has been released in 2014! No, you absolutely shouldn't use that - the current release is 7.0.99 (Dec 2019). And you should stay on top of minor releases, as they contain security fixes. Don't go back to be so horribly outdated as you currently are (I can't even find Tomcat 4.1.2 in the archives - the earliest 4.1.x that I find is 4.1.10 from Sep 2003)

Comment: Sorry my bad ..its 8 not 7 actually .yeah you are right and this is what my point to the management . I cant help i am stuck in such place where so out of date technology is being used :(  i will leave it up to them to decide if they find it worth cost and effort for the application to be recompiled if its actually being used .my suggestion is same to use the latest version which is 9 for tomcat and accordingly rest and recomplie the code . Thanks alot for your help and time :)

Comment: Microsoft never supports the ISAPI approach, so if you insist on that part you take the risks. What Microsoft suggests is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/manjug/understanding-iis-httpplatformhandler-using-tomcat-8